# Rearranging a string based on specific requirements

Tags: python, list

Hi there so I am looking to build this python function with simple things like def, find etc. so far I know how to get the first part of the code.

Given a string such as "HELLODOGMEMEDOGPAPA", I will need to return a list that gives me three things:

Everything before the word dog which i will denote as before_dog
The word dog until dog appears again dog_todog
Everything after the second time dog appears will be denoted by after_todog
The list will be in the form [before_dog,dog_todog,after_todog].

so for example given ("HELLODOGMEMEDOGPAPADD") this will return the list
("HELLO","DOGMEME","DOGPAPADD")

another example would be ("HEYHELLOMANDOGYDOGDADDY") this would return the list
("HEYHELLOMAN","DOGY","DOGDADDY")

but if I have ("HEYHELLODOGDADDY")
the output will be ("HEYHELLO","DOGDADDY","")

also if dog never appears ("HEYHELLOYO") then the output will be ("HEYHELLOYO,"","")

This is what I have so far:

```
def split_list(words):
    # declare the list
    lst = []
    # find the first position
    first_pos=words.find("DOG")
    # find the first_pos
    before_dog = words [0:first_pos]
    lst.append(before_dog)
    return lst
```

Comment: should it be case-sensitive?

Comment: no does not have to be case sensitive

Comment: upvote for doggos n puppers

Comment: What is wrong with what you have so far? What does it return? How does this differ from what you expect it to return?

Comment: It will help if you write the steps to solve this problem *in words*. If you do this, you will see that you have already implemented some of those steps in the code you gave here. You will also see that you are missing a few steps to finish this.

Answer (score 1):

Funny function `split_2_dogs()` with `re.findall()` function:

```
import re

def split_2_dogs(s):
    if s.count('DOG') == 2:   # assuring 2 dogs are "walking" there
        return list(re.findall(r'^(.*)(DOG.*)(DOG.*)$', s)[0])

print(split_2_dogs("HELLODOGMEMEDOGPAPADD"))
print(split_2_dogs("HEYHELLOMANDOGYDOGDADDY"))
```

The output:

```
['HELLO', 'DOGMEME', 'DOGPAPADD']
['HEYHELLOMAN', 'DOGY', 'DOGDADDY']
```

---

Alternative solution with `str.index()` and `str.rfind()` functions:

```
def split_2_dogs(s):
    if 'DOG' not in s: return [s,'']
    pos1, pos2 = s.index('DOG'), s.rfind('DOG')
    return [s[0:pos1], s[pos1:pos2], s[pos2:]]
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without any ifs and just slicing or import

Comment: hey roman so how would I go about doing it if I wanted the first time dog appeared to always be in the second part of the list even if there is only one time that dog appears in the given string?

Comment: @KirusanS, see my **last** update in the second approach

Answer (score 0):

Splitting at `DOG` is the key!! This code will for all the cases that you have mentioned.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

words = 'HEYHELLODOGDADDY'
words = words.split("DOG")
words = ['DOG'+j if i>0 else j for i,j in enumerate(words)]
# words = ['HEYHELLO', 'DOGDADDY']
ans = ['','','']
# stitch words and ans together
ans = [m+n for m,n in izip_longest(words,ans,fillvalue='')]

print ans
```

Output :

```
['HEYHELLO', 'DOGDADDY', '']
```

Comment: what would I do if the dog does not appear the second time? then I just get an error

Comment: @KirusanS So you are saying that for `HELLODOGPAPA` answer should be `('HELLO','DOGPAPA','')`

Comment: yes that is what it should be and if there is a second occurence of the string DOG then everything after including the second occurrence of dog will be the third part of the list

Comment: do you know if this would be possible just by using the find and slicing functions with strings?

Comment: @KirusanS First tell me, do you want to use the `split()` or not?

Comment: yes please splitting a string to give me back the three strings in the list

Comment: I added in some more examples to the main question If you know what I am getting at

Comment: @KirusanS Final answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do using the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function. For example, you can split any string by a delimiter, like dog, as so:

```
>>> chunks = 'HELLODOGMEMEDOGPAPA'.split('DOG')
>>> print(chunks)
['HELLO', 'MEME', 'PAPA']
```

You could then use the output of that in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like so:

```
>>> dog_chunks = chunks[:1] + ["DOG" + chunk for chunk in chunks[1:]]
>>> print(dog_chunks)
['HELLO', 'DOGMEME', 'DOGPAPA']
```

The only slightly tricky bit is making sure you don't prepend dog to the first string in the list, hence the little bits of [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).

Answer (score 0):

`Split` the string at 'DOG' and use conditions to get the desired result

```
s = 'HELLODOGMEMEDOGPAPADD'
l = s.split('DOG')
dl = ['DOG'+i for i in l[1:]]
[l[0]]+dl if l[0] else dl
```

Output:

```
['HELLO', 'DOGMEME', 'DOGPAPADD']
```